# Getting individual entries of a Set in Java?

Tags: java, string, list, object, set

So I am currently having a problem understanding how to access a set, is that even allowed? So I understand my set of names contains a set of Character objects. I also understand that my `toString()` method call converts these Character objects into a String, but not a conventional string -- which is why I have `[s,a]` rather than `[sa].` So my question is, is if there is a way to make me have a list of individual strings. So I want my list to be = `[s, a]` rather than `[ [s,a] ].` Is this even possible? I apologize if this makes no sense; nevertheless, if you do understand my fumbled explanation thank you for your time and help. If you need for me to explain more, I will.

```
    //this all works
    Set<Character> names = find(prefix).getRollCall().keySet();
    //[s,a]
    String lists = names.toString();
    //[s,a]
    List<String> sloop = Arrays.asList(lists);
    //[[s,a]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a `Set<Character>` to a `List<Character>` you can do

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>(set);
```

If you want to convert a `Set<Character>` to a `List<String>` you can do

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (char c : set)
    list.add("" + c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `toString()` at all. Iterate over the elements of the `Set` and build up whatever string you like.

```
Set<Character> names = find(prefix).getRollCall().keySet();
for (Character c : names)
{
    // whatever you like
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain what's happening in your code, in case you aren't clear:

```
String lists = names.toString();
```

This calls the standard `toString` method for a collection which converts your set to an ordinary (conventional) string in a standard format (i.e. comma delimited, in brackets). There's nothing special about the string that is created: "[s, a]".

```
List<String> sloop = Arrays.asList(lists);
```

The `asList` method takes one or more arguments and converts them into a list. Because you've given it only a single argument `lists` it creates a list with a single string element: ("[s, a]")

Then, later, I suspect you are doing something like:

```
System.out.println(sloop);
```

This again calls the standard `toString` method for a collection (in this case the `List` sloop) and again creates a comma delimited, bracket enclosed standard string: "[[s, a]]"

So, most of that is probably not what you want. Your `lists` variable isn't a `List`, it's a `String` which I assume isn't what you want.

If you are just looking to convert your set of character to a list of strings, then this is pretty trivial in Java 8:

```
List<String> lists = names.stream().map(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```